# Square root in number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algorithms, computational-number-theory, number-fields

I'm trying implement an algorithm that, for an element $b$ of a number field $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$,  if it is a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ (i.e., $\exists x\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):x^2=b$), computes the square root $x$. If $b$ is not a square, try to compute an $x'\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $x'^2-b\in\mathbb{Q}$.

It was known to me that if $b$ is guaranteed to be a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, its square root can be computed (e.g., by using $p$-adic method). However, these questions remains unknown to me:

1. How can one determine if $b$ has a square root in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ or not?
2. If $b$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, in what circumstances there is an $x'\in\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that $x'^2-b\in\mathbb{Q}$? Is such an $x'$ guaranteed to exist?
3. When the $x'$ in 2 exists, how to compute it?

Comment: Concerning question (1), this may not be the most efficient thing to do, but you can certainly apply algorithms for factoring polynomials over number fields (Googling “factoring polynomials over number fields” returns many relevant results) to factor $X^2 - b$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)[X]$.

Comment: (1) If you can compute square roots of numbers that are known to be squares, you can also determine whether a given element $b$ is a square or not: just run the square root algorithm on $b$, and check if the result $x$ (if any) satisfies $x^2=b$. If $b$ is a square, then the algorithm is guaranteed to compute a square root of $b$, thus the test is positive. If $b$ is not a square, then either the algorithm fails due to running into some sort of internal inconsistency, or it computes a garbage number $x$ whose square in any case cannot be $b$, as $b$ is not a square. Thus, the test is negative.

Comment: Q1: Finding roots of (or factoring) polynomials over number fields is easy computationally, there are polynomial time algorithms, e.g. in PARI/GP there is Belabas's variant of van Hoeij's algorithm. So you can just factor or find the roots of $x^2-b$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is meant to answer only your second question.

**Claim.** Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\alpha = \sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{4} \in K$. Then there does not exist $\beta \in K$ such that $\beta^2-\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$.

More generally, any square in $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{d})$ is of the form
$$
(x+y\sqrt[3]{d}+z\sqrt[3]{d^2})^2=x^2+2dyz+(2xy+dz^2)\sqrt[3]{d}+(y^2+2xz)\sqrt[3]{d^2}.
$$
So, if for every $\alpha \in K$ there exists $\beta \in K$ such that $\beta^2-\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$, that means that for every $b,c \in \mathbb{Q}$ there exist $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Q}$ satisfying
$$
2xy+dz^2 = b,~~y^2+2xz=c.
$$
This is an intersection of two quadrics in three-dimensional space, which defines a curve of genus $1$ if it is non-singular. Eliminating $x$, we obtain
$$
bz-dz^3=cy-y^3,
$$
which is a plane cubic curve with the rational point $P=(0,0)$ on it (which on the intersection of the two quadrics corresponds to the point at infinity).

In fact $P$ is a *flex* or *inflection point*, meaning that the tangent to $P$ (which is simply given by the linear part of the equation of the curve, so by $cy-bz=0$) has intersection multiplicity $3$. Considering the equation of the cubic in homogeneous form,
$$
bX^2Z-dZ^3=cX^2Y-Y^3,
$$
the coordinates of the point $P$ are now $(1:0:0)$ and its tangent is $cY-bZ=0$. If you look in Cassels' book on elliptic curves, you find that you can transform a cubic with a flex $P$ into Weierstrass form by a linear transformation which maps $P$ to the point $(0:1:0)$ and its tangent to the line $Z=0$. The first can be achieved by just interchanging the roles of $X$ and $Y$, i.e. by considering the new curve
$$
bY^2Z-dZ^3=cXY^2-X^3,
$$
where now the point $P$ has coordinates $(0:1:0)$ and tangent equal to $cX-bZ=0$. If we further replace $Z$ by $(cX-Z)/b$, we will obtain a Weierstrass curve (up to a simple scaling of $X$ and $Y$). The substitution $Z \mapsto (cX-Z)/b$ yields $Y^2(cX-Z)-d(cX-Z)^3/b^3=cXY^2-X^3$, where you already see the $XY^2$ terms cancelling each other, producing the equation $-b^3 Y^2Z - d(cX-Z)^3=-b^3 X^3$, or after rearranging terms $b^3 Y^2Z = b^3 X^3 - d(cX-Z)^3$. Now we change back to affine coordinates $x$ and $y$, and we obtain $b^3 y^2 = b^3 x^3 - d(cx-1)^3$. We expand and collect the cubic terms:
$$
b^3 y^2 = (b^3- c^3d) x^3 + 3c^2dx^2 - 3cdx + d.
$$
We get rid of the coefficients of the highest powers in $x$ and $y$ by multiplying everything by $b^3(b^3- c^3d)^2$ and replacing $x \mapsto x/(b(b^3- c^3d))$ and $y \mapsto y/(b^3(b^3- c^3d))$. We then get:
$$
y^2 = x^3 + 3bc^2dx^2 - 3b^2cd(b^3- c^3d)x + b^3d(b^3- c^3d)^2.
$$
Now this is a Weierstrass curve which is isomorphic (even projectively equivalent) to the cubic curve we started with, so in the case where it has no other points except $(0:1:0)$, we will know that the original system of two quadratics has no solutions. (Also conversely, if it does have non-trivial points, then the system does have a solution.)

For this, we can use for example Sage. When we do that, for example putting as I did $d=2$, $b=1$, $c=-1$, we will find that the resulting Weierstrass curve is $y^2=x^3+6x^2+18x+18$, and that its group of rational points is the trivial group. $\square$

---

The answer to the part "How does one determine whether there exists $\beta$ such that $\beta^2-\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}$?" probably has to be that one simply has to solve the equations (which means finding points on a curve given as the intersection of $d-1$ quadrics in $d$-dimensional space). I don't think there is anything else for it. Even in the degree $3$ case there seems to be no short-cut available.

Comment: Thank you for your insight on the question 2. I used to have an intuition that a non-square number can have a "small non-square residue" cut off and become a square. It is true for $\mathbb{Q}$ and any quadratic number field, but as you have pointed out, this fails to be true for number fields whose degree is at least 3. When the degree goes higher, it will require me to find rational points on curves with higher and higher genus, which doesn't seem fruitful.